# PDA accepting of a specific symmetric language

Tags: regular-languages, pushdown-automata

Assume we have PDA that accepts a specific symmetric language on $\{a,b\}^*$.

if we have $a$ This side of the string, on the other side of the string we have $aa$.
and if we have $b$ This side of the string, on the other side of the string we have $bb$.

Examples of words in this language (middle point emphasized):

$ab\, bbaa$

$aaa\, aaaaaa$

$bab\, bbaabb$

What is a PDA accepting this language?

I can find a grammar for this language but I can't find a PDA.

The grammar: $S \to aSaa \mid bSbb \mid aaa\mid bbb$

Answer (score 1):

There are general constructions that give a PDA given a CFG.

In this case, start with the PDA for $\{a^n b^n \colon n > 0\}$, instead of storing one $A$ on the stack for each input $a$, store two, and the same for $b$. When reaching the middle, start discounting and accept by empty stack.